# Gmail Api Python: function delete not working

Tags: google-apis-explorer

I get the id of my message between 2 dates, but it is impossible to delete this messages by their id in my program.
Because I going always in my exception code "erreur suppression".

I have tested in the "Try api" with the same settings and it's work: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/delete?apix_params=%7B%22userId%22%3A%22me%22%2C%22id%22%3A%2216be66c1f679ceee%22%7D#auth

The type of content is a string also like the type of the id api.

I use this method: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/python

And here is the code useful:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import print_function
from datetime import date, timedelta, datetime
import pickle
import os.path
import time
import datetime
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from apiclient import errors

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly']


def main():

    creds = None

    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.

    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)

    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.

    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file('credentials.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server()

        # Save the credentials for the next run

        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)

    debut = input("Entrez la date de début de supression des messages au fomat JJ/MM/AAAA : ")
    fin = input("Entrez la date de fin de supression des messages au format JJ/MM/AAAA : ")

    ts_debut = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(debut, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())
    ts_fin = time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(fin, "%d/%m/%Y").timetuple())

    debut = int(ts_debut)
    fin = int(ts_fin)



    query = 'after:' + str(debut) + 'AND before:' + str(fin)

    results = service.users().messages().list(userId='me', labelIds=['INBOX'], q=query).execute()

    # Call the Gmail API

    messages = results.get('messages', [])
    user_id = 'user email address'
    if not messages:
        print('No labels found.')

    # Dates have to formatted in YYYY/MM/DD format for gmailelse:

    print('Labels:')
    for messages in messages:
        content = messages['id']
        try:
            message = service.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=content, format='metadata').execute()
            try:
                service.users().messages().delete(userId=user_id, id=content).execute()
                print("")
            except errors.HttpError:
                print ("erreur")

            print(content)
        except:
            print('erreur date')


main()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the answer, my scope was false: gmail.readonly changed to https://mail.google.com/ for Full access to the account, including permanent deletion of threads and messages.

Go to this link for more informations: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/auth/scopes